# Flutter: The Method isn't defined?

Tags: flutter, dart

Im currently designing a 'whats in my fridge' style application for college. The first page Ive started on is the recipes page. I wish for it to retrieve the recipes from this API (Spoonacular.com) and simply display them on the recipe page. Im having trouble with this error *"The method 'recipesFromSnapshot' isn't defined for the type 'Recipe'"* on the last line of code on this api file `return Recipe.recipesFromSnapshot(_temp);`. I can't see the issue as it declared in the recipe.dart file? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**RECIPE.API.DART FILE**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:best_before/models/recipe.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:best_before/models/recipe.dart';


class RecipeApi{
  static Future<List<Recipe>> getRecipe() async{
    var uri = Uri.https('spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.rapidapi.com', '/recipes/search',
        {'query': 'burger','diet': 'vegetarian','excludeIngredients': 'coconut','intolerances': 'egg, gluten','number': '10','offset': '0','type': 'main course'});

    final response = await http.get(uri,headers:{
      'x-rapidapi-host': 'spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.rapidapi.com',
      'x-rapidapi-key': 'API KEY',
      'useQueryString':'true'
    });

  Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
  List _temp = [];

    for (var i in data['results']){
      _temp.add(i['0']);
    }

    return Recipe.recipesFromSnapshot(_temp);
}

}
```

**RECIPE.DART FILE**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class Recipe{
  final String name;
  final String images;
  final String id;
  final String readyInMinutes;
    Recipe({
    @required this.name,
    @required this.images,
    @required this.id,
    @required this.readyInMinutes,
  });

  //Recipe({this.name, this.id, this.totalTime});

  factory Recipe.fromJson(dynamic json){
    return Recipe(
      name: json['title'] ?? '',
       id: json['id'].toString(),
      images: 
      "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/${json['id']}-556x370.${json['imageType']}",
      readyInMinutes: json['readyInMinutes'].toString(),
    );
  }
}

class RecipeList {
  final List<Recipe> list;
    RecipeList ({
      @required this.list,
    });
  
  factory RecipeList.fromJson (List<dynamic> json) {
    return RecipeList(
      list: json.map((data) => Recipe.fromJson(data)).toList(),
    );
  }

   static List<Recipe> recipesFromSnapshot(List snapshot){
     return snapshot.map(
     (data){
         return Recipe.fromJson(data);
       }).toList();
   } 
  @override
     String toString(){
       return 'Recipe {name, images, id, readyInMinutes}';
     }
}
```

Comment: `recipesFromSnapshot` is defined on `RecipeList` not `Recipe`. Also FYI, you appear to be using an outdated version of dart.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to call the correct method from the correct class. Per comment:

> `recipesFromSnapshot` is defined on `RecipeList` not `Recipe`

Rechecking your code, it seems that you defined the method `recipesFromSnapshot` in class `RecipeList`:

```
class RecipeList {
  final List<Recipe> list;
    RecipeList ({
      @required this.list,
    });
  
  factory RecipeList.fromJson (List<dynamic> json) {
    return RecipeList(
      list: json.map((data) => Recipe.fromJson(data)).toList(),
    );
  }

   static List<Recipe> recipesFromSnapshot(List snapshot){ // This is where it is defined
     return snapshot.map(
     (data){
         return Recipe.fromJson(data);
       }).toList();
   } 
  @override
     String toString(){
       return 'Recipe {name, images, id, readyInMinutes}';
     }
}
```

You might consider changing your return call to return `RecipeList.recipesFromSnapshot(_temp);`